# discord.py-rewrite Not able to add reaction, 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make it so when my bot reacts to the `help` command, it DMs them and reacts with a checkmark, however when trying to react, i get this error `'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'` Heres what i tried.

```
reaction = ""
await bot.add_reaction(emoji=reaction)
```

### EDIT/EXTRA

I also tried `await ctx.add_reaction(emoji=reaction)`

Comment: Grab the Message object when you DM the user. `msg = await member.send...`. Then simply do `await msg.add_reaction...`

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine Got an error, `NameError: name 'member' is not defined`

Comment: never mind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SOLUTION

What i did was the following.

```
reaction = ""
await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji=reaction)
```